# Unable to establish SSH session under no-ip services on raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, noip

I'm trying to setup a raspberry pi (OS: Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS) in order to connect through ssh on default port 22.

I'm using a 4G sim with a TpLink Archer MR 600; my ISP is assigning me a private dynamic IP address so I managed to configure a ddns using the free no-ip services.

- Created an hostmane called "robman.ddns.net", I'm able to resolve it using nslookup.
- Installed noip2 package for dynamic IPs management
- Assigned a fixed IP to my raspberry, reserving it on the router
- Opened ports on my router via Virtual servers and port triggering
- Started the ssh session on the pi 4

When I try to connect to it using `ssh -vvv ubuntu@robman.ddns.net` I received Connection-timeout but if I try to connect using the private local IP address I'm able too establish an SSH session.

---

**nmap scan**

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-27 17:52 CEST
Nmap scan report for robman.ddns.net (***.**.***.***)
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.22 seconds
```

---

As another note: when I try to execute `ping robman.ddns.net` the address seems to be solved but the ping it seems to be stuck!

---

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

---

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: Where are you connecting from? What is the DNS server on that device? For Windows: ipconfig /all | findstr DNS. For Linux: cat /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Added requested detail into the question